Average number of comparisons to find all minimum values
I'd like to find the average number of comparisons for finding ALL minimum values in an array.
The code would look something like this:
let all_min = [(0, vec[0])]
let cur_min = vec[0]

for i in 1..vec.len() {
  if vec[i] == cur_min {
    all_min.push((i, vec[i]))
  } else if vec[i] < cur_min {
    cur_min = vec[i]

    all_min.clear()
    all_min.push((i, vec[i]))
  }
}

In the best case, the entire array will be one value. Thus, the second if statement will never be explored and only n - 1 comparisons will be made.
In the worst case, the array will be a reversed sorted array. Thus, the second if statement will ALWAYS be explored and 2 * (n - 1) comparisons will be made.
However, I'm really struggling to calculate the average number of comparisons made. If anybody could walk me through the process, that would be amazing.

If the input is completely random and the array values unbounded, then the probability that there is an equality is infinitesimally small. That is enough to say that the expected number of comparisons is 2(n-1). Note that it doesn't matter whether the second if condition is true or not, in either case the comparison is made.

Typically, when looking at the asymptotic complexity of algorithms, you only make one comparison, not two like vec[i] == cur_min and vec[i] < cur_min. That would give you n-1 comparisons, which you can't beat. Why? Think about removing one more, which would mean that one element never gets compared with, so its value, which might be another minimal value, isn't considered. Of course, that would lead to faulty results.

@UlrichEckhardt How do you find ALL minimum values with n-1 comparisons?

@nocomment, I don't understand what you mean with that question. The algorithm is described in the question mostly.

@UlrichEckhardt You seem to be saying that you can always do it with n-1 comparisons, and I don't see how that's possible. So I'd like to see how.

Okay, @nocomment. If you look at the code in the question, it does that almost. The only thing that is needed is to make a single comparison to determine whether a value is equal, less or greater than another value instead of making two comparisons.

@UlrichEckhardt And how do you do that?

Do what, @nocomment?

@UlrichEckhardt That: "make a single comparison to determine whether a value is equal, less or greater than another value"

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison, @nocomment.

@UlrichEckhardt And that's supposed to be "Typically"? I don't think so. Plus you  then probably have even more comparisons in order to react to the different outcomes of the three-way comparison.

The only way to define an "average" number of comparisons is to define a probability space for the possible inputs.
For instance, you could say:

For a given N and K, the input consists in N independent uniformly-random integers in range [1, K]

and calculate the expected number of comparisons under that assumption. The expected value you get will be expressed as a function of K and N.
The calculation would actually be easy with this assumption: expectation is linear, which means that the expected number of comparisons is exactly the sum of the expected number of comparisons (1 or 2) at each iteration of the loop; and each of these numbers are equal to 2 - 1/K (because there is probability 1/K to have an equality at each iteration), so the expected total number of comparisons is (N-1) * (2-1/K), or if you prefer (N-1) * (2K-1)/K. You can check that this is consistent with the worst-case and best-case that you have already calculated: if K == 1, all elements are equal, so the number of comparisons is N-1; and if N is fixed but K goes to infinity, then the probability of an equality goes to zero and the number of comparisons goes to 2(N-1).
If you make a different assumption, you should get a different result.
If you don't make any assumption about the probability space that the inputs are drawn from, then it isn't even defined what "average" means.
You've probably read books that say "The average number of comparisons of quicksort is O(n log(n)).", without making any explicit assumption on the inputs, and while glossing over the details of the calculation to get this result. This is pretty imprecise and usually requires the additional assumption that the number of equal elements is low and the list is uniformly randomly shuffled. If the shuffle is not uniformly random or if the list contains many duplicates elements with high probability, then this result is false. For instance, in the degenerate case where all elements are equal, all elements will always be sent to the same side of the pivot, and the total running time will be n^2, not n log(n).

I wonder what the optimal way is. I think I can do it with about n+2*log2(m) comparisons in the worst case, where m is the number of minimum values.
